# Python: Scraping a Jobs Portal Site

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I just started learning how to use Python to explore scraping a jobs portal site - so please bear with me as I may ask very fundamental questions.

Situation:
I've managed to build out the following lines

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ - Home/Desktop/Web Scraper/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.mycareersfuture.gov.sg/search?sortBy=relevancy&page=0')

results =[]
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
listing= soup.find('div', class_ = 'card-list')
job = listing.find('p')
print(job)
```

Complication: I can't seem the extract the following items from the job card:

1. Job title
2. Company name
3. Salary

I've looked up several tutorials and each of them have indicated to look for h2 tags or divs with the respective classes. However, the site that I'm scraping doesn't appear to have this explicitly stated.

Link to site: https://www.mycareersfuture.gov.sg/search?sortBy=relevancy&page=0

For example, I've inspected the HTML and found the job title to be somewhere in this line; however, I just can't seem to extract it.

```
<span data-cy="job-card__job-title" class="f4-5 fw6 mv0 dib mr2 brand-sec JobCard__jobtitle___3HqOw" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">2402 - IT Manager [ Amber Rd /   /  5 days ]</span>
```

I would really appreciate any help on this. I've been researching for solutions all night but to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```py
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# set headless mode
# options.add_argument("--headless")
# disable chromedriver log message in cmd
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])

service = Service(executable_path='path\to\your\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# set an explicit wait (10 sec)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'https://www.mycareersfuture.gov.sg/search?sortBy=relevancy&page=0'

# page where parsing will stop
last_page = 5225
# loads a web page
driver.get(url)

while True:
    try:
        # waiting(max 10 sec) for least one element with our css selector present on a web page.
        company_names = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[data-testid="company-hire-info"]')))
        job_titles = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-cy="job-card__job-title"]')))
        salaries = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="lh-solid"]')))
    except TimeoutException:
        # if TimeoutException refresh the page and try again
        driver.refresh()
        continue
    # get data from received web elements
    for data in zip(company_names, job_titles, salaries):
        data = {
            'Company name': data[0].text,
            'Job title': data[1].text,
            'Salary': data[2].text
        }
        # save received data in csv
        with open(file='mycareersfuture.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerow([data['Company name'], data['Job title'], data['Salary']])

    # waiting for an element is present on the DOM of a page. after that click on it
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Next"]'))).click()
    # if the current page is equal to the last_page stop parsing
    if driver.current_url.endswith(str(last_page)):
        break

driver.quit()
```

Output mycareersfuture.csv:

```
THE SUPREME HR ADVISORY PTE. LTD.,2402 - IT Manager [ Amber Rd / / 5 days ],$6 500to$7 000
TRITON AI PTE. LTD.,"Property Executive, Town Council (Facilities Management)",$2 000to$3 000
PISTACHIO RESTAURANT PTE. LTD.,Service Crew / Supervisor,$1 700to$3 000
THE SUPREME HR ADVISORY PTE. LTD.,2402 - Quantity Surveyor [ Admiralty / 5 days ],$3 000to$3 500
THE SUPREME HR ADVISORY PTE. LTD.,2402 - WSH Co-ordinator [ 5 days / WSQ Advanced Cert ],$2 200to$3 500
```

Comment: Thanks for this potential solution! I'm now able to scrape the other items such as applications, seniority etc.

I know this is asking for a lot, but would it be possible to add comments on the items that you've introduced? I'm very new to all of these terms and have little understanding around how it works. It would be super helpful for me to understand the logic behind each function. 

Separately, how would I go about to export the data into a .CSV for example?

Comment: @DepthVader updated the answer and added ability save data to csv

Comment: this is super helpful. You have no idea how helpful this is for me. Moving forward, how would I go about to automatically end the scraper if i have hit the last page before my hard-coded criteria? I'm guessing I would need to write an if statement - but not too sure the syntax

Comment: It looks like the scraper is breaking at around page 30. I'm guessing this is because of anti-scraping mechanisms implemented? Off the top of my head, I'm thinking of implementing the following logic to circumvent this: 1) If time on page is more than X seconds then stop 2) Restart scraper from the last stopped page. Not sure how to code this actually...

Comment: @DepthVader I think it would be better to handle the TimeoutException that occurs when the page does not contain the elements we need. And after that, as you said, refresh the page and try again.
I have updated the answer

Comment: this is amazing. Thanks so much for your help! :)

What would be the best way for me to ramp up and learn the basics of web scraping - so that I would be able to independently handle exceptions / edge cases moving forward?